# Disable zsh session folder completely

Tags: macos, mac, shell, zsh

I recently switched from Ubuntu to macOS Big Sur 11.1, and Apple is using `zsh` as their default shell .The `.zsh_sessions` folder is taking up about 100 MB and I want to disable it completely, although I could delete normally.

I have added following in my `.zshrc` but it was of no use:

```bash
set hist_ignore_all_dumps
setopt hist_ignore_space
setopt HIST_NO_FUNCTIONS
SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0
```

I want to disable creation of `.zsh_sessions` folder completely.

Comment: I thinkbthe folder `zsh_sessions` is non-standard, are you using some third-party plugins, like OMZ?

Comment: @mpy no , I did not install any plugins

Comment: Ok, then maybe its a MacOS "feature" (read: something shipped by default via `/etc/zshrc` for example). I use Linux only, so I cannot help you there. Maybe https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/35746/unify-your-macos-terminal-command-history can help you, there `touch ~/.zsh_sessions_disable` is mentioned to disable these Terminal sessions mechanism.

Comment: @zsh Do you think you could Accept my answer?

Answer (score 9):

The code that sets up macOS's "Save/Restore Shell State" feature for Zsh can be found in `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal`. As explained in that file, to disable this feature, you need to do the following:

1. In your home dir, create a plain text file named `.zprofile`.
2. In this file, add the following:

   ```bash
   export SHELL_SESSIONS_DISABLE=1
   ```

### Why you need to put the variable in `~/.zprofile`

When Zsh is started as an *interactive* shell (login or not), it will source `/etc/zshrc` and `~/.zshrc`, in that order. If (and only if) macOS’s `/etc/zshrc` runs inside Terminal.app, it calls `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal`, which starts the “Save/Restore” feature. This means that you cannot set the variable to disable this feature in `~/.zshrc`, because that file is read only *after* the feature has already been started and “restored” your previous session.

However, whenever you open a new tab or window in Apple’s Terminal.app, it starts a new interactive *login* shell. When a Zsh login shell starts up, it sources `~/.zprofile` and does so *before* sourcing `/etc/zshrc`.

### Why you need to `export` the variable

Interactive shells that are descendants of a login shell are not automatically themselves login shells. Thus, if you would disable the feature in each login shell by only *setting* the variable, then any subshell started with, say, `exec zsh`, would still start up with the “Save/Restore” feature enabled.

To fix this, you need to `export` the variable. This puts it into the shell's *environment.* Each child process inherits its parent’s environment, with all the variables in it. This way, you ensure that the “Save/Restore” feature is also disabled in interactive shells that are descendants of the login shell, but not necessarily login shells themselves.

Comment: I added some explanation why not to use `~/.zshenv`

Comment: Do you mean `ZDOTIDIR` or `ZDOTDIR`?

Comment: @aSemy Whoops! That was a typo. Now I fixed it.

Comment: This is a great way to [disable separate session history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36880385/35690) as well. You can exploit that fact to verify that the `.zprofile` changes took effect by running `echo $HISTFILE`. If it outputs `~/.zsh_history`, it successfully disabled zshell sessions.

Answer (score -2):

You can switch to bash, and bash also logs sessions in an analogous ~/.bash_sessions file, or folder - if you prefer, everything in UNIX is actually a file. But, to prevent the creation of sessions files in /bin/bash, "touch ~/.bash_sessions_disable"

If you don't like the message about apple switching to zsh, you don't have to see it if you switch from Apple's Terminal, to iTerm2.  iTerm2 is by far, better, and while you are at it, get brew, and then brew install bash, and don't use apple's bash at all.

I suggest getting iTerm2, forgetting apple's Terminal all together, and for that matter, get the open source bash, and point to it in iTerm2 as your either login or non-login shell.

To this question, look at these two files, and see how this sessions stuff is implemented.:

```
/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal
/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal
```

They are sourced in the normal "apple Terminal" start-up sequence.  Do a man on bash and/or man zsh.